# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to update some of my modules in my app so i changed a module's version and fixed some problems with the build by changing the gradle version and the build tools and the android plugin version .

anyway after that i'm having an Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac error and i looked online for it everywhere (i even read all the questions about it here but i didn't find anything that will help me fix the problem i'm having right now -i even tried multiple solutions as well-)

i'm not getting this error when i build and sync my project but i'm getting it when i try to run the project

1-
[image]

2-
[image]

3-
[image]

4-
[image]

module gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }



 dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call

    }
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.labayh"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 22
    versionName "1.5.4"
    multiDexEnabled true
    manifestPlaceholders = [HOCKEYAPP_APP_ID: "5b5787324c7a46f98cdc66acd2404594"]

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
}
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':rangeseekbar')
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

//    implementation project(':PayFort')
    implementation project(':library')
    //implementation files('libs/libjingle_peerconnection.jar')
    /*compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.7.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }*/
    //implementation files('libs/base_java.jar')
    implementation project(':FORTSDKv1.4.3')

//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:1.2.3@aar'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.merhold.extensiblepageindicator:extensiblepageindicator:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.10@aar'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.18.0'
implementation 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.0.0'
implementation 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:5.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'

/*implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.6.0'*/

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
//implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.nex3z:notification-badge:0.2.0'
implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.victor:lib:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.shamanland:fonticon:0.1.8'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46'
implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.1'
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.6.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.+'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl:15.0.0'
//implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.shadow-layout:library:1.0.1'
implementation 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk-base:4.0.5'
implementation 'com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.4.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.appsee:appsee-android:+'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4+@aar'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'

/*
 * record view
 */
implementation 'com.github.safetysystemtechnology:audio-recorder-button:v1.3'

/**
 * TokBox and easy permissions
 * */
implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.opentok.android:opentok-android-sdk:2.14.0'

/**
 * ButterKnife
 * */
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

/**
 * Calendar
 * */
implementation 'com.github.applikeysolutions:cosmocalendar:1.0.4'

// fortsdk new one..

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

api project(path: ':FORTSDKv1.4.3')

api 'com.victor:lib:1.0.1'

api 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
api 'com.shamanland:fonticon:0.1.8'
api 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'


api('com.nispok:snackbar:2.11.+') {
    // exclusion is not necessary, but generally a good idea.
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
}

api 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
api 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk16:1.46'
api 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.11'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

project gradle ::

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
        maven { url 'https://tokbox.bintray.com/maven' }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my project settings gradle :

```
include ':app', ':rangeseekbar', ':library', ':FORTSDKv1.4.3'
```

the module i was trying to upgrade is FORTSDK1.4.3 (this is the new version )

the output of gradle  clean assembleDebug ::

```
    > Configure project :app
WARNING: The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
It will be removed at the end of 2018..
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Configure project :library
WARNING: The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
It will be removed at the end of 2018..
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.0) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.4.
Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used.
To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '27.0.0'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.

> Configure project :rangeseekbar
WARNING: The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
It will be removed at the end of 2018..
WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation' and 'testApi'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:clean
> Task :library:clean
> Task :rangeseekbar:clean
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :library:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :library:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Transform FORTSDKv1.4.3.aar (project :FORTSDKv1.4.3) with ExtractAarTransform
> Transform FORTSDKv1.4.3.aar (project :FORTSDKv1.4.3) with ExtractAarTransform
> Transform FORTSDKv1.4.3.aar (project :FORTSDKv1.4.3) with ExtractAarTransform
> Task :library:checkDebugManifest
> Transform 282a617b37c05600dd284dbe60659b77 with AarTransform
> Transform 282a617b37c05600dd284dbe60659b77 with AarTransform
> Transform 282a617b37c05600dd284dbe60659b77 with AarTransform
> Task :library:processDebugManifest
> Task :rangeseekbar:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :rangeseekbar:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :rangeseekbar:checkDebugManifest
> Task :rangeseekbar:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:preDebugBuild
> Task :library:compileDebugAidl
> Task :rangeseekbar:compileDebugAidl
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl
> Transform FORTSDKv1.4.3.aar (project :FORTSDKv1.4.3) with ExtractAarTransform
> Transform 282a617b37c05600dd284dbe60659b77 with AarTransform
> Task :library:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :rangeseekbar:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :app:prepareLintJar
> Transform FORTSDKv1.4.3.aar (project :FORTSDKv1.4.3) with ExtractAarTransform
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug
> Transform FORTSDKv1.4.3.aar (project :FORTSDKv1.4.3) with ExtractAarTransform
> Transform FORTSDKv1.4.3.aar (project :FORTSDKv1.4.3) with ExtractAarTransform
> Transform 282a617b37c05600dd284dbe60659b77 with LibrarySymbolTableTransform
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
> Transform 282a617b37c05600dd284dbe60659b77 with AarTransform
> Transform 282a617b37c05600dd284dbe60659b77 with AarTransform
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets
> Task :library:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :library:compileDebugShaders
> Task :library:generateDebugAssets
> Task :library:packageDebugAssets
> Task :rangeseekbar:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :rangeseekbar:compileDebugShaders
> Task :rangeseekbar:generateDebugAssets
> Task :rangeseekbar:packageDebugAssets
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/google-services.json

> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :library:compileDebugRenderscript
> Task :library:generateDebugResValues
> Task :library:generateDebugResources
> Task :library:packageDebugResources
> Task :rangeseekbar:compileDebugRenderscript
> Task :rangeseekbar:generateDebugResValues
> Task :rangeseekbar:generateDebugResources
> Task :rangeseekbar:packageDebugResources
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
> Task :app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug
> Task :library:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :library:prepareLintJar
> Task :library:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :library:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :rangeseekbar:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :rangeseekbar:prepareLintJar
> Task :rangeseekbar:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :rangeseekbar:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
> Transform FORTSDKv1.4.3.aar (project :FORTSDKv1.4.3) with ExtractAarTransform
> Task :rangeseekbar:platformAttrExtractor
> Task :rangeseekbar:generateDebugRFile
> Task :rangeseekbar:generateDebugSources

> Task :rangeseekbar:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: /home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/rangeseekbar/src/main/java/org/florescu/android/rangeseekbar/RangeSeekBar.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/rangeseekbar/src/main/java/org/florescu/android/rangeseekbar/RangeSeekBar.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :rangeseekbar:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug
> Transform 282a617b37c05600dd284dbe60659b77 with AarTransform
> Task :library:platformAttrExtractor
> Task :library:generateDebugRFile
warning: string 'b20hg' has no default translation.
> Task :app:processDebugResources
> Task :app:generateDebugSources
> Task :library:generateDebugSources

> Task :library:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: /home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/library/src/main/java/com/github/gfranks/collapsible/calendar/widget/DayView.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/library/src/main/java/com/github/gfranks/collapsible/calendar/CollapsibleCalendarView.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :library:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:41: error: package com.payfort.start does not exist
import com.payfort.start.Card;
                        ^
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:42: error: package com.payfort.start does not exist
import com.payfort.start.Start;
                        ^
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:43: error: package com.payfort.start does not exist
import com.payfort.start.Token;
                        ^
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:44: error: package com.payfort.start does not exist
import com.payfort.start.TokenCallback;
                        ^
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:45: error: package com.payfort.start.error does not exist
import com.payfort.start.error.CardVerificationException;
                              ^
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:46: error: package com.payfort.start.error does not exist
import com.payfort.start.error.StartApiException;
                              ^
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
public class PaymentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TokenCallback {
                                                                  ^
  symbol: class TokenCallback
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:83: error: cannot find symbol
    private Start start = new Start(API_OPEN_KEY);
            ^
  symbol:   class Start
  location: class PaymentActivity
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:335: error: cannot find symbol
    public void checkLastFour(View view, Card card) throws CardVerificationException {
                                         ^
  symbol:   class Card
  location: class PaymentActivity
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:335: error: cannot find symbol
    public void checkLastFour(View view, Card card) throws CardVerificationException {
                                                           ^
  symbol:   class CardVerificationException
  location: class PaymentActivity
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:354: error: cannot find symbol
    public void createToken(View view, Card card) {
                                       ^
  symbol:   class Card
  location: class PaymentActivity
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:532: error: cannot find symbol
    public void createCard(final Card crd) {
                                 ^
  symbol:   class Card
  location: class PaymentActivity
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:678: error: cannot find symbol
    private Card unbindCard() throws CardVerificationException {
            ^
  symbol:   class Card
  location: class PaymentActivity
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:678: error: cannot find symbol
    private Card unbindCard() throws CardVerificationException {
                                     ^
  symbol:   class CardVerificationException
  location: class PaymentActivity
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:739: error: package Card does not exist
    private void setErrors(EnumSet<Card.Field> errors) {
                                       ^
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:760: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                          ^
  symbol:   class Token
  location: class PaymentActivity
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:768: error: cannot find symbol
    public actionablevoid onError(StartApiException e) {
                        ^
  symbol:   class StartApiException
  location: class PaymentActivity
17 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 42s
56 actionable tasks: 55 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Comment: Run "gradlew clean assembleDebug" and update the question with the output of that command.

Comment: project gradle google() repository first declare

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska  DONE :)     

thanks again for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i could detect the problem when i used the command gradlew clean assembleDebug as @IzabelaOrlowska suggested

thank you for your help and i hope that everyone else will find it a little bit easier to fix this build error after reading this answer.

after i changed the FORTSDK to the new version they changed the integration of their services a  lot so i ended up with a lot of undefined methods and classes in the java section of the code but i didn't check them at first because i didn't except for them to change so many things

---

as stated in the last output of the gradlew clean assembleDebug which is ::

```
 > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:41: error: package com.payfort.start does not exist
import com.payfort.start.Card;
                        ^
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:42: error: package com.payfort.start does not exist
import com.payfort.start.Start;
                        ^
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:43: error: package com.payfort.start does not exist
import com.payfort.start.Token;
                        ^
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:44: error: package com.payfort.start does not exist
import com.payfort.start.TokenCallback;
                        ^
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:45: error: package com.payfort.start.error does not exist
import com.payfort.start.error.CardVerificationException;
                              ^
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:46: error: package com.payfort.start.error does not exist
import com.payfort.start.error.StartApiException;
                              ^
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
public class PaymentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TokenCallback {
                                                                  ^
  symbol: class TokenCallback
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:83: error: cannot find symbol
    private Start start = new Start(API_OPEN_KEY);
            ^
  symbol:   class Start
  location: class PaymentActivity
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:335: error: cannot find symbol
    public void checkLastFour(View view, Card card) throws CardVerificationException {
                                         ^
  symbol:   class Card
  location: class PaymentActivity
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:335: error: cannot find symbol
    public void checkLastFour(View view, Card card) throws CardVerificationException {
                                                           ^
  symbol:   class CardVerificationException
  location: class PaymentActivity
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:354: error: cannot find symbol
    public void createToken(View view, Card card) {
                                       ^
  symbol:   class Card
  location: class PaymentActivity
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:532: error: cannot find symbol
    public void createCard(final Card crd) {
                                 ^
  symbol:   class Card
  location: class PaymentActivity
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:678: error: cannot find symbol
    private Card unbindCard() throws CardVerificationException {
            ^
  symbol:   class Card
  location: class PaymentActivity
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:678: error: cannot find symbol
    private Card unbindCard() throws CardVerificationException {
                                     ^
  symbol:   class CardVerificationException
  location: class PaymentActivity
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:739: error: package Card does not exist
    private void setErrors(EnumSet<Card.Field> errors) {
                                       ^
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:760: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                          ^
  symbol:   class Token
  location: class PaymentActivity
/home/akumanotatsujin/AndroidStudioProjects/Android-Labayh/app/src/main/java/com/labayh/customer/activity/PaymentActivity.java:768: error: cannot find symbol
    public actionablevoid onError(StartApiException e) {
                        ^
  symbol:   class StartApiException
  location: class PaymentActivity
17 errors
```

so they basically changed the way i get the token so all the old classes ended up undefined ...

and that was the cause of my error...

Comment: So what was the problem? would you make your answer a bit clear for future searches and accepting it ? Thanks. This helps the community.

Comment: i will edit it right away but i can't accept my own answer unless it has been published for 2 days ...